# A Particular Version of The Lagrange Mean Value Theorem for Complex Valued Functions

Tags: complex-analysis, periodic-functions, mean-value-theorem

I am given the following homework question to work with:
[image]

I am done with parts (a) and (b). But I cannot work on other parts because the concepts are not clear to me: what is exactly meant by "projection along a line" in part (c)? What is exactly the "closed convex hull" of a set in part (d), and why we can consider the functions of the form $\text{Re}[e^{i\theta} f(t)]$? I searched the terms on the internet but the results are not quite applicable to my level (I am taking an introductory second year complex analysis course).

Any hints to parts (c) and (d) would be appreciated a lot.

Comment: The convex hull of a set is the set $E$ is the set of the (finite) convex combinations of elements of $E$ (i.e. $\sum t_i e_i$ with $\sum t_i = 1$, $t_i \geq 0$, and $e_i \in E$), and the closed convex hull is simply the (topological) closure of the convex hull, i.e. in this context it is the set you obtain by considering all limits of sequences of the convex hull, which will correspond to the infinite convex combinations of elements of $E$.